# How to copy message from channel to channel in discord?

Tags: python, copy, discord, message, discord.py

I'm trying to program a bot that can copy a message from one channel to another from any channel in discord, but the code that I typed in was not working even though I'm sure I followed the documentations correctly (hopefully).

```
@bot.command() #Moves a message from channel to channel
async def copymessage(ctx, message_id, channel_id):
    """
    Copy a message from channel to channel
    """
    guild = ctx.guild
    channel = guild.get_channel(int(channel_id))
    message = guild.fetch_message(int(message_id))
    print(f'Copying {message_id} to {channel_id}')
    await channel.send(message)
```

I have tried using a similar code (shown below) to test if I followed correctly. This code ran successfully and did what it was supposed to do.

```
channel = guild.get_channel(623681100778176513)
await channel.send("Sparkle is online!")
```

Maybe there's someone that can help me figure out the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

[`fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message) is an attribute of `Messageable`s (guilds are not messageable), so you need to use the `channel.fetch_message`.  It also must be awaited.

```
message = await channel.fetch_message(int(message_id))
```